# Pydantic: How to parse JSON with custom property name

Tags: python, pydantic

How can I define a mapping between a json property to a pydantic model where the property name is different?. ie:

```py
# I want to parse thumbnailUrl into thumbnail
class ChatMessageAttachment(BaseModel):
    id: str
    thumbnail: Optional["str"] = None

external_data = {"id": "123", "thumbnailUrl": "www.google.es"}
chat_message = ChatMessageAttachment(**external_data)
print(chat_message) # >>>id='123' thumbnail=None
```

Comment: why not replace the key `thumbnailUrl` with `thumbnail` in the data dict beforehand?

Comment: That was my first solution indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Pydantic, you can use aliases for this. In the code below you only need the `Config` `allow_population_by_field_name` if you *also* want to instantiate the object with the original `thumbnail`. If you only use `thumbnailUrl` when creating the object you don't need it:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional

class ChatMessageAttachment(BaseModel):
    id: str
    thumbnail: Optional["str"] = Field(None, alias="thumbnailUrl")
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


external_data = {"id": "123", "thumbnailUrl": "www.google.es"}
chat_message = ChatMessageAttachment(**external_data)

print(chat_message) 
#  id='123' thumbnail='www.google.es
```

With `allow_population_by_field_name` you can also do:

```
external_data = {"id": "123", "thumbnail": "www.google.es"}
ChatMessageAttachment(**external_data)
# ChatMessageAttachment(id='123', thumbnail='www.google.es')
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the `alias` usage in pydantic. I like it, clean and simple.